# SQLServer.exe using 100% CPU (on Windows Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server

For the last few days, our CPU usage is at 100%. I have checked Task Manager and it shows `msSQLServer.exe` is utilizing 98% CPU. Also whenever I unplugged server's network cable; server runs fine...

Please see the attached screenshots for reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9aNL.jpg)

Comment: That looks extremely suspicious to me, and almost certainly NOT SQL Server, probably some malware that is hijacking your machine's resources made to look like something innocent - Right-click, select Properties and add a screenshot of the dialog you see.

Comment: Two things: 1. I am yet to see any Microsoft product using "MS" as a prefix; you normally do not configure SQL Server to run under System account: I support @pcdev suggestion that it could be malware. 2. Please indicate (and add links) if you have posted the same question  on multiple sites: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acb518a2-7352-48bd-9901-61f5e71454ef/mssqlserverexe-using-100-cpu-windows-server-2012?forum=sqlexpress

Comment: @Alex, as a matter of fact, SQL Server itself uses the MS prefix as the [default instance name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143744(v=sql.90).aspx), which you can see if you check a server running SQL Server under the Services tab, but not under the Processes tab, AND Microsoft would never allow it to be prefixed "Ms", that's just plain sloppy.  That was the biggest tip-off to me.  If it had been all uppercase, I would have probably taken some time to realise it wasn't actually SQL Server!

Comment: Thanks - Where should I Right-Click and select Properties from ? I am beginner with SQL Server

Comment: Locate the file on disk and right click->Properties. Look for Digital Signatures tab, check that it has a Microsoft signature.

Comment: On the Task Manager item that says "MsSQLServer"

Comment: @pcdev - I stand corrected re "MS". For general reference: the executable should be called sqlservr.exe and should be digitally signed.

Comment: Thanks - I will share the properties detail shortly. I have Symantec Endpoint Protection installed on MS Server 2012 machine, could some malware still harm the SQL server?

Comment: No malware protection is totally secure, so yes, you could still be infected.

Comment: @Reyan - for the benefit of others I would encourage you write an answer to this question and accept it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Symantec Endpoint Protection was running on Server, and I've done a complete scan of Windows Server but it couldn't detected the malware. However; I installed another Malware Scanner, it scanned **RiskWare.BitCoinMiner** Threat in 3 files with the name and location at **c:\Users\MSSQLSERVER.exe** with Object type: File, Processes & Processes Module and Quarantine these files. After complete scan CPU became normal (10% CPU usage now). Thanks all for support!

[I have attached scan result here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHXFF.jpg)